# How do I propagate asymmetric error/confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, error, measurement, error-propagation

Assume that I have two measurements with asymmetric error, $X^a_b$ and $Y^c_d$, and  I want to find $Z^e_f = X^a_b + Y^c_d$. How do I find Z?

The type of answer I'm looking for is of the form : $e = F(X, Y)$ and $f = G(X, Y)$ or a reference to a paper that has solved this.

Thanks for your help.

**Updates**:
So the confidence interval for $X^a_b$ would be (X - b, X + a). They can be independent and the distributions are not exactly gaussian since a≠b and c≠d. They would have some positive skewness.

This is a general question, but you can assume that the intervals as stated, are with 68% confidence. The confidence intervals were calculated as : $0.34 = \int^{X+a}_XdX*PDF(X)$ and $0.34 = \int^{X}_{X-b}dX*PDF(X)$, with PDF(X) being the normalized distribution of X.

X and Y are independent.

Comment: Can you please explain your notation? What *is* $X_b^a$? independence? distributions?

Comment: So the confidence interval for $X^a_b$ would be (X - b, X +a). Then can be independent and the distributions are not exactly gaussian since $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$. They would have some positive skewness.

Comment: Understanding your meaning requires you to disclose some of the implicit assumptions.  How do you know the error is asymmetric?  How do you estimate the quantities $X_b^a$ and $Y_d^c$?  What are you assuming about the distribution of errors?  In what sense are these confidence intervals?  Please include this clarifying information within the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for the edit--but details are important.  Answering your question requires knowing *how* the confidence intervals are constructed, as well as knowing what you assume about these measurements.  For instance, are they independent?

Comment: I have updated the post with more information